# How to make this white?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, path, clipping-mask

I am making a reverse logo but am running some issues. Can anyone help me figure out how to make this zero in this logo white, just like the draft picture.

Thank you.

[image]
[image]

Comment: In Illustrator?  Then change the fill color.

Comment: @BillyKerr it's possible that the letters are all one shape and just a knockout of the main circle.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you cannot change the fill color of the 0, because 360 is a single shape.

You can check, if the structure can be exploded (= release compound paths, release clipping masks, ungroup) and then recomposed, but with a white zero.

If you are in a hurry, simply place a white ring above the zero.

[image]

There are two circles, both filled, but without a stroke. At first a white circle is placed over the zero. It's opacity is reduced to see the right size and placement. It must be a little too big, making an exact snapping piece easily leaves a black ring when the result is exported.

In the middle there's a blue circle. It must be a little too small and it must be on the top.  See NOTE1

Both circles are selected, a hole is generated with Object > Compound Path > Make. The opacity is returned to 100%

[image]

NOTE1: If the grey color is a single solid color without a slightest gradient, you can simply recolor the blue circle to the same color, let it be and it's there with no holes.